# How to run a .py file converted to binary using spark-submit ( In linux)

Tags: linux, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a python script ( .py) in which I have python/pyspark code , I am running it using the command :  spark-submit filename.py.

Now , I want to share my file with other people , but don't want them to know the code/logic. So I converted the python file in binary using pyinstaller, but now I am having trouble running the code.
( The problem is that the spark-submit needs to run the file before executing it , but binary file can only be executed)

Please tell , if there any solution to above ?

Comment: Bear in mind that using Pyinstaller only "package" the code but source is still completely readable as it was written.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What trouble do you have running the code? How do you try to run it? What happens? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this we have an option of using Java or Scala. If possible convert you code into Scala or Java, and then create an executable of it which is normally a .jar file. Afterwards share the same jar file with the people you want and they will be able to run it. A command like this can help:

```
spark-submit --class com.example.testjar /path/to/file.jar
```

You can't do the same with pyspark since it needs a .py file in such a way that it also compiles properly, which means code inside the python file and not binary.